# Track when user clicks on buttons in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am making a basic news website with different API's. I want to track in local storage which news articles the user clicks on and reads. At the moment it doesn't track when I click the `link-btn`, but instead it tracks when I reload the site.

The last code in the script is supposed to be the code to track when the user clicks the different articles. I know how to make it track if I click only 1 btn/article, but how do I track when there are multiple articles?

```js
const apiKey = "API-KEY";
// display the news on the page
const fetchNews = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=d1b8b964fce34d61aa47037c7155f638"
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

let bigNews = document.getElementById("bigNews");
let smallNews1 = document.getElementById("smallNews1");
let smallNews2 = document.getElementById("smallNews2");
let smallNews3 = document.getElementById("smallNews3");
let smallNews4 = document.getElementById("smallNews4");
let smallNews5 = document.getElementById("smallNews5");
let smallNews6 = document.getElementById("smallNews6");

const displayNews = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  bigNews.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="bigNewsImg" src="${news.articles[0].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[0].title}</h5>
    <a href="${news.articles[0].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `; //display the news on the page with the help of the template literal
};

displayNews();

//Ovenstående Kode er skrevet af GitHub Copilot

/*const displayBigNews = async () => {
  bigNewsImage = document.querySelector("bigNewsImage");
  bigNewsText = document.getElementById("bigNewsText").value;
  bigNewsTitle = document.getElementById("bigNewsTitle");
  bigNewsLink = document.getElementById("bigNewsLink");

  const news = await fetchNews();
  bigNewsImage.setAttribute("src", news.articles[0].urlToImage);
  //bigNewsText.innerHTML = news.articles[0].description;
  bigNewsLink.innerHTML = news.articles[0].url;
};
displayBigNews();*/

const displaySmallNews1 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews1.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews1Img" src="${news.articles[1].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[1].title}</h5>
    <a href="${news.articles[1].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews1();

const displaySmallNews2 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews2.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews2Img" src="${news.articles[2].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[2].title}</h5>
    <a href="${news.articles[2].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews2();

const displaySmallNews3 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews3.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews3Img" src="${news.articles[3].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[3].title}</h5>
    <a href="${news.articles[3].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews3();

const displaySmallNews4 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews4.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews4Img" src="${news.articles[4].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[4].title}</h5>
    <a href="${news.articles[4].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews4();

const displaySmallNews5 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews5.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews5Img" src="${news.articles[5].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[5].title}</h5>
    <a onclick="userArticles" href="${news.articles[5].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews5();

const displaySmallNews6 = async() => {
  const news = await fetchNews();
  smallNews6.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card">
  <img id="smallNews6Img" src="${news.articles[6].urlToImage}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${news.articles[6].title}</h5>
    <a onclick="userArticles" href="${news.articles[6].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
};

displaySmallNews6();



// track when the user clicks on btnLink in local storage

const userArticles = () => {
  let userArticles = localStorage.getItem("userArticles");
  if (userArticles == null) {
    userArticlesObj = [];
  } else {
    userArticlesObj = JSON.parse(userArticles);
  }
  userArticlesObj.push("userArticles");
  localStorage.setItem("userArticles", JSON.stringify(userArticlesObj));
}

userArticles();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#outerContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
}

#leftside {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #373b53;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#heart {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: beige;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/105/105220.png);
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#house {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: beige;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-512.png);
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #373b53 0% 9.09%, white 9.09% 90%);
}

#input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  border: auto;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-512.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-size: 20px;
}

#login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#profile {
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: auto;
  background-color: #373b53;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#userName {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(206, 201, 201);
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#nyheder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bigNews {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

#smallNewsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#smallNews1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#smallNews2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#smallNews3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#smallNews4 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#smallNews5 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#smallNews6 {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#readMoreBtn1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#readMoreBtn2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#readMoreBtn3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#readMoreBtn4 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#readMoreBtn5 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#readMoreBtn6 {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  background-position: bottom left;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#tidogvejr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px;
  width: auto;
}

#current-time {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#sunriseSunset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vejrprognose {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#solopgang {
  font-size: large;
  width: 50%;
}

#sunrisePNG {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/77-775474_its-a-sun-peaking-halfway-up-over-the.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

#sunset {
  font-size: large;
  width: 50%;
}

#sunsetPNG {
  display: flex;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/287/287668.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

#logOutImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/339-3396821_png-file-svg-download-icon-logout-transparent-png.png");
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: center;
  border-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#bigNewsImg {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews1Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews2Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews3Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews4Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews5Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#smallNews6Img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-size: small;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.btnLink {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for news" id="input" />
  <div id="login">
    <div id="userName"></div>
    <button id="profile" onclick="goToProfile()">Go to profile</button>
    <button id="logOutImg" onclick="logOutClick()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div id="leftside">
    <div id="heart"></div>
    <div id="house"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nyheder">
      Nyheder
      <div id="bigNews">
        <div id="bigNewsText"></div>
        <div id="bigNewsImage">
          <div id="bigNewsLink"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="smallNewsContainer">
        <div id="smallNews1">
          <div id="smallNews1Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews1Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="smallNews2">
          <div id="smallNews2Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews2Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="smallNews3">
          <div id="smallNews3Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews3Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="smallNews4">
          <div id="smallNews4Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews4Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="smallNews5">
          <div id="smallNews5Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews5Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="smallNews6">
          <div id="smallNews6Img"></div>
          <div id="smallNews6Text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tidogvejr">
      Tid
      <div id="current-time"></div>
      <h3>Vejr</h3>
      <div id="sunriseSunset">
        <div id="solopgang" class="solopgang"></div>
        <div id="sunrisePNG"></div>
        <div id="sunset" class="sunset"></div>
        <div id="sunsetPNG"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="vejrprognose" class="weatherWidget">Vejrprognose API</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @chazsolo please only put code into snippets if it can run as a snippet. LocalStorage can not run in snippets.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for the tip, I will do that next time!

Comment: Why would you push `userArticles` to the array in `userArticlesObj.push("userArticles")`? `userArticles` seems to be the local storage content (or null) that you have already extracted, or set, `userArticlesObj` to.

Comment: @DavePritlove It was just to check that the the content would be placed in an array. I think my problem is that i dont know, how what to 'push' so it says that i "user clicked article 1" etc...

Comment: @Tange007 ok thanks. I would try sending some attribute of the clicked item (id or value perhaps) to the function as an argument: `userArticles(id)` (with the value represented by 'id' being collected in a click-event), and pushing that value to the storage array: `userArticlesObj.push(id)`. You can then access each stored article by looping through the retrieved `userArticlesObj` array, processing each item as required.

Comment: @Tange007 I've posted an answer expanding on my comment suggestion with a snippet to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

This working snippet uses a variable named `storedStuff` as a proxy for `local storage` (as storage doesn't function here). It may point you in the right direction.

Your function has to know when an article has been clicked in order to add it to the store. The snippet achieves this with a click event listener that passes the ID of the relevant article to the function (you could pass any attribute, value or innerText or HTML).

The function receives the ID information as an argument and that is what is stored. A `parsed` version of the stored JSON can be processed by iterating the storage array, and its stored values used however you wish (in this case to display console messages of the accumulated storage)

```js
const articles=document.querySelectorAll(".article");

for (let i=0; i<articles.length; i++) {
  articles[i].addEventListener('click', e => userArticles(e.target.id));
} // next article;
/*
const userArticles = (id) =>  {
  console.clear();
  console.log(id);
}
*/
let storedStuff;

const userArticles = (id) => {
  console.clear();
  let userArticles = storedStuff;
  if (userArticles==null) {
    userArticlesObj = [];
  } else {
    userArticlesObj =
  JSON.parse(userArticles);
  }
  userArticlesObj.push(id);
  // store to local storage here;
storedStuff=JSON.stringify(userArticlesObj); 

// console.log(userArticlesObj)

  userArticlesObj.forEach(element => {console.log(`article with id ${element} has been visited`);
  })

}
```

```css
.article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 3em;
  width: 12em;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article" id="art1">article 1</div>
<div class="article" id="art2">article 2</div>
<div class="article" id="art3">article 3</div>
<div class="article" id="art4">article 4</div>
```

In order to apply this principle to your example, the function needs to receive an argument that is sent by a function call from an event listener attached to each article. Your revised function would be:

```
const userArticles = (id) => {
  let userArticles = localStorage.getItem("userArticles");
  if (userArticles == null) {
    userArticlesObj = [];
  } else {
    userArticlesObj = JSON.parse(userArticles);
  }
  userArticlesObj.push(id);
  localStorage.setItem("userArticles", JSON.stringify(userArticlesObj));
}
```